# Nested Sass to select and affect only the first level menu anchors not the sub-menus

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Here I am trying to give the top level menu bar a different height than the sub-menu items.

Seems `first-child` affects all the menu items (menu & sub-menu items) though it should only affect the menu items, don't know exactly what is the cause, and how to solve it with a neat solution without using extra class selectors or adding an !important rule.

Please take a look at the code, full code is also provided.

**HTML Code:**

```
      <ul class="menu"> 
        <li class="active">
          
          <a href="#s1">Perfumes</a>
          
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
          </ul>
          
        </li>

        <li>
          
          <a href="#s2">Gemstones</a>
          
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
          </ul>
          
        </li>
     
      </ul>
```

**Sass (SCSS) - Showing the focused parts:**

---

**In menu section I have:**

```
.menu
  a {
    &:first-child {
      height: 80px; line-height: 80px; // It applies to all the menu
      and sub-menu items, we want it to just be applied to the top
      menu bar items!
    }
  }
```

**In SubMenu I have:**

```
.submenu {
  
  & > li {
    
    a {
      height: 50px;  line-height: 50px;  
      // height: 50px !important;  line-height: 50px !important;
      // This works, but don't want to use !important, want to find other
        workarounds and the issues here       
    }
  }
```

**Note:** I prefer not to use additional class selectors, just I like to use the advanced/nested Sass selectors.

**Full Code:**  [Code is here](https://codepen.io/Kasrak1/pen/dyVVoqg?editors=1100)

Comment: I don't know about sass but the css that you are generating is `.menu > li a:first-child` so, it will affect ALL first child  <a> in all submenus . You should generate `.menu > li > a {}`, this will affect just  the <a>'s inside first level (Perfumes and Gemstones)

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I think I also tried that in my code earlier, If you had time, could you please provide a simple working one similar to the structure I used with just the CSS change you mean (in CodePen possibly), then I will convert it, and re-check if I missed anything and is it working in my scenario or not. Also would be glad if you take back your down-vo-te if you did, anyway thanks, appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qgpbs6mr/  I used your html and your css (compiled). notice I commented the compiled css line 25 and added the line 30

Comment: TBH at the same time you were writing it, I also made it working, you were right, BTW I remember that I tried for the "a" earlier inside menu section with some advanced filtering and it didn't work, though now that it is inside the submenu section "a" selector did the job, I missed to try it there. thanks, if you like write an answer with the 2,3 lines you mentioned here and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Done. gl with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about sass but the css that you are generating is .menu > li a:first-child so, it will affect ALL first child  in all submenus . You should generate .menu > li > a {}, this will affect just the 's inside first level (Perfumes and Gemstones):

```
.menu > li > a {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgpbs6mr/) I used your html and your css (compiled). notice I commented the compiled css line 25 and added the line 30

Comment: May I ask you one thing, earlier in the menu sample the sub-menu, didn't have a gap, now it seems it is somehow aligned to the right-side. Do you know what is the cause? In your own sample you can see the effect.

Comment: thats because codepen has his own "reset.css" sheet and Jsfiddel does not. Notice the jsfiddle when I add all reset rules: https://jsfiddle.net/avhk4eyq/  If you don't want to add those rules, just add `ul {padding:0;}` (all HTML  lists have padding by browser default)

Comment: right, nice, didn't notice it.